# Undefined variable in view, Laravel 5.3

Tags: model-view-controller, view, laravel-5.3

Hi Im trying to display my data from the database to my views in Laravel 5.3

But Im having this error

> Undefined variable: guests (View: C:\Users\NtechB02-Chu\Desktop\laravel_projects\2fplaza\resources\views\admin\guests.blade.php)

This is my declare routes

```
Route::resource('/guests', 'GuestController');
```

and my Controller

```
  public function index()
{

  $guests = DB::table('users')->where('roles_id', '2')->orderBy('id')->chunk(10, function($guests) {
      foreach ($guests as $guest) {
          echo $guest->firstname . $guest->lastname;
      }

      return false;
  });

  return view('admin.guests', ['users' => $guests]);
}
```

Lastly my views file

> @foreach ($guests as $guest)
>     {{$guest->firstname}}
>
> @endforeach

I hope you could help me guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!

Instead of doing the query inside my controller I placed in the AppServiceProvider under the folder App/Providers

```
use View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function boot()
  {
    $guests = DB::table('users')->where('roles_id', '2')->first();

    View::share('guest', $guests);
  }
```

I was bale to access it in my views

Answer (score 0):

return view('admin.guests', ['guests' => $guests]);
or you can alternatively do.

return view('admin.guests')->('guests', $guests)->render();

Comment: The foreach statement I put in my controller works. But the ones in the views is not working because of the variable error

Comment: Try {{ dd($guests) }} do you get anything.

Comment: found a solution. I posted it below

Answer (score 0):

> you have  send users variable how can guest can be fetch in forloop
>    *do like this*

```
 public function index()
{

  $guests = DB::table('users')->where('roles_id', '2')->orderBy('id')->chunk(10, function($guests) {
      foreach ($guests as $guest) {
          echo $guest->firstname . $guest->lastname;
      }

      return false;
  });

  return view('admin.guests',compact('guests'));
}
```